# Thread.sleep inside of for loop to update ImageView

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, scenebuilder

I have a JavaFX program where I have 2 dice that I want to be able to click on, have them "animate" and then stop. To do this, I have a for loop that will run 15 times and each iteration will change the image view of each of the 2 dice to a different die face and will create a flickering effect, making it look like the dice are rolling. At the end of each iteration I am using Thread.sleep() to pause very briefly. The time does not need to be precise or accurate so I didn't feel like doing it this way would be much of a problem.
Unfortunately, the dice do not animate and instead just pause for a moment before settling on the 15th iteration. Seen a couple of solutions on Swing but hoping to get one for JavaFX. Thanks!!

```
Image[] diceImages = {
            new Image("dOne.png"),
            new Image("dTwo.png"),
            new Image("dThree.png"),
            new Image("dFour.png"),
            new Image("dFive.png"),
            new Image("dSixFixed.png")
    };

public void rollDice() throws InterruptedException {

        Random random = new Random();
        int d1CurrentIndex = 5;
        int d2CurrentIndex = 5;
        int numberOfDieBounces = 15;

        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfDieBounces; i++){

            boolean newNumberIsSameAsOld = true;
            while(newNumberIsSameAsOld){
                int randomIndexD1 = random.nextInt(6);

                if(randomIndexD1 != d1CurrentIndex){
                    d1CurrentIndex = randomIndexD1;
                    newNumberIsSameAsOld = false;
                }
            }

            newNumberIsSameAsOld = true;
            while(newNumberIsSameAsOld){
                int randomIndexD2 = random.nextInt(6);

                if(randomIndexD2 != d2CurrentIndex){
                    d2CurrentIndex = randomIndexD2;
                    newNumberIsSameAsOld = false;
                }
            }

            Thread.sleep(100);
            firstDie_img.setImage(diceImages[d1CurrentIndex]);
            secondDie_img.setImage(diceImages[d2CurrentIndex]);
        }

        int totalSpaces = d1CurrentIndex + 1 + d2CurrentIndex + 1;
        moveToSpace(totalSpaces);
    }
```

Comment: Use `Timeline` or `AnimationTime`.

Comment: The ideas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45392535/javafx-text-animation-from-array/45402872#45402872) should help.

Comment: The reason that they don't animate is that JavaFX uses the FXAT to run the screen updates.  The code that you have here is running on the FXAT, and occupies it completely even while the sleep() is running.  Each loop changes the layout, but all of the updates are painted on the screen AFTER your code finishes running.

Comment: You could take a look at my article here: https://www.pragmaticcoding.ca/javafx/elements/sprites that talks about doing the kind of thing that you want.

Comment: @SedJ601 Oh I completely forgot about Timeline, that's definitely what I want to use, thank you!!!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966136/javafx-periodic-background-task, particularly [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60685975/2189127).